# Different p values using glmer vs glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I'm not sure whether this is more of a StackOverflow question or a Cross Validated question, but here it goes.  I tried running a GLM comparing measures of my variables between genders (sampling units=id).

```
dat<-structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,     2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), H = c(1.70472411119393,     1.36337467178795, 2.03419240701723, 2.3862073321169, 1.86086450126479,     1.60339904804508, 2.45952727265204, 1.78184706115844, 1.88076761164771,     1.87370412991099), Richness = c(31L, 17L, 26L, 24L, 28L, 15L,     28L, 30L, 14L, 14L), D = c(0.609682276753607, 0.543344841230054,     0.799682602658203, 0.855536471866238, 0.719298957361353, 0.679820415879017,     0.865266149133977, 0.678392426480618, 0.730893527819024, 0.755637179879604    ), id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,     -10L))

summary(glm(H~Gender,data=dat))
```

Out of curiosity, I checked it against a GLMM that (I thought) should have been equivalent.

```
summary(glmmPQL(H~Gender,random=~1|id,family=gaussian,data=dat))
```

Sure enough, when I used a Gaussian error distribution in the GLMM, it gave the same p value as the GLM.  However, when I tried to do the same thing with integer data using a Poisson error distribution, it produced a different p values.

```
summary(glm(Richness ~ Gender, family = poisson, data = dat))
summary(glmer(Richness ~ Gender + (1 | id), family=poisson, data=dat))
```

Is this something I should be concerned about?  Is one approach preferable over the other in this case?  I'm guessing the simpler GLM, but want to be sure.  Thanks!

Comment: the `glmer` version includes an observation-level random effect, which incorporates overdispersion.  You'll get a similar (but not identical) result with `glm(..., family=quasipoisson)`

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker!

Answer (score 2):

The `glmer` version includes an observation-level random effect, which incorporates overdispersion. You'll get similar (but not identical) results with other approaches that allow for overdispersion:

- `glm(..., family=quasipoisson)`
- `MASS::glm.nb(...)`  (no `family=` argument because this function is specialized for negative binomial models)

In your Gaussian models, there are two confounded (jointly unidentifiable) variance terms (among-'group' and residual variance); this is not reported by `glmmPQL` or `nlme::lme()` but will throw an error with `lme4::lmer()`. It doesn't  (in principle) affect the estimation of the fixed effects, but (1) it may cause numerical problems and (2) if you look at the confidence intervals on the variance terms you'll find they're effectively infinite because any (non-negative) combination of variances will fit the data equally well.